# Superscript page numbers with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, superscripts

I'm with an annoying problem with `natbib`. When the `super` parameter is used, the citation happily goes superscript but the page or chapter number doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers, square, super]{natbib}
\begin{document}
    Some information.\cite[p.~56]{who09}

    \begin{thebibliography}{0}
        \bibitem{who09} Who J F. Nice Book. 2009.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The above example shows the page number into normal text instead of superscript. Removing `super` the page goes into brackets.

Comment: I've never seen anyone give references in the way you suggest. Can you point to a place where this is used?

Comment: @joseph, Neither do I. I just want to be consistent in writing free style documents for class.

Comment: @JosephWright. I suspect it's the only citation format many people will have encountered as it's the format used on Wikipedia.

Comment: it's helpful to point out that AMA citation style uses precisely the format indicated by the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although this citation style is not common (as **Joseph Wright** suggested in his comment), you can obtain the desired result with a redefinition of the natbib's internal macro `\NAT@citesuper`. Here's a working example of such a redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers, square, super]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@citesuper[3]{\ifNAT@swa
\if*#2*\else#2\NAT@spacechar\fi
\unskip\kern\p@\textsuperscript{\NAT@@open#1\if*#3*\else,\NAT@spacechar#3\fi\NAT@@close}%
   \else #1\fi\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text\cite[p.~56]{who09} some text\cite{who09}

\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\bibitem{who09} Who J F. Nice Book. 2009.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has helped me a great deal, works well for \citep, how can the same workaround be applied for \citet, which shows the same behaviour as the initial question....

Comment: This breaks in XeLaTeX when certain fonts (e.g. some versions of Linux Libertine) are used with the `xltxtra` package.  The solution then is to replace `\textsuperscript` in the definitions of `\NAT@citesuper` with `\textsuperscript*`.  Note this will then break if the use of `xltxtra` is removed.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot comment, so I feel the urge to post this as an answer. While the exact example asked for is (as was repeated) non-common, there is a very common use for this modification: Turning it into subreferences as in [1a], [1b], by adding the corresponding letter into square brackets `\cite[a]{foo}, \cite[b]{foo}` Also works with Natbib.

I modified Gonzalo's code snippet by looking at it and guessing which parts would be too many. Probably more code could be removed but I have no idea which that could be, and this is the first working example. (I am specifically suspecting anything containing `#2` to be irrelevant, but I do not want to continue researching into this, as I have a thesis to hand in soon.)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@citesuper[3]{\ifNAT@swa
\if*#2*\else#2\NAT@spacechar\fi
\unskip\kern\p@\textsuperscript{\NAT@@open#1#3\NAT@@close}%
\else #1\fi\endgroup}
\makeatother
```