# Refer to previous reference, different page numbers in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to tell Bibtex to refer to a previous citation, but with different page numbers?  Ideally, the citation in the bibliography would say something like

```
[23] Ref. 20, pp. 33-45
```

if `Ref. 20` was the previous reference and 23 was the superscript number shown in the text.

**Edit**

Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[square,comma,super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Hello there.\cite{firstref}  I found this.\cite{secondref}  I also 
found these\cite{firstref:differentpage,secondref:otherdifferentpage} on 
different pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is helpful.  However, one standard approach would be something like `\cite[p.~40]{paper1}` and `\cite[pp.~33--45]{paper1}`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann:  Thought about adding a minimal working example, but decided the question was straightforward enough.  I can add one if people think it's necessary

Comment: Without the MWE we don't know which citation style you are using, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Okay, done.  Also specifies a use case that doesn't seem to work with your first suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output by abusing the bibliography in the following way.  Note that each entry in the bib file can refer to others in via the usual citation mechanism; you just end with more rounds of compilation.  So the first step is to set-up references for the subsequent uses that contain citations to the original article.

Now using `natbib` its punctutation of the bibliography behaves badly if there is no `author` or `year` field.  So against my better judgement, you put the infomation into the `year` field, rather than a `note` or `howpublished` (`author` could be used, but `bibtex` plays too many games with that).

The output:

[image: Sample output]

is obtained from the latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[square,comma,super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Hello there.\cite{firstref}  I found this.\cite{secondref}  I also 
found these\cite{firstref:differentpage,secondref:differentpage} on 
different pages, but note this case\cite{firstref:yetanotherpage}.
However\cite{secondref:differentpages}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

with `ref.bib` containing

```
@Article{firstref,
  author =   {Author, One},
  title =    {Title One},
  journal =  {J. One},
  year =     2011,
  pages =    {1--50}
}

@Article{secondref,
  author =   {Author, Two},
  title =    {Title Two},
  journal =  {J. Two},
  year =     2012,
  pages =    {40--69}
}

@Misc{secondref:differentpage,
   year = {Ref.~\citenum{secondref}, p.~41}
}

@Misc{secondref:differentpages,
  year = {Ref.~\citenum{secondref}, p.~39--40}
}

@Misc{firstref:differentpage,
  year = {Ref.~\citenum{firstref}, pp.\ 1--10}
}

@Misc{firstref:yetanotherpage,
  year = {Ref.~\citenum{firstref}, p.~6}
}
```

after running

```
latex file
bibtex file
latex file
latex file
```

(In general this sort of situation could require two `bibtex` runs.)

Note I could not find examples of this type of citation style in use searching the web.  The closest I got was a [description of a Chicago format](http://www.write.armstrong.edu/handouts/ChicagoFormat.pdf) where subsequent references are short author, short title, page.  A [description of an AMA style](http://chua2.fiu.edu/faculty/haskins/pht6970/ama%20style.htm) has page numbers in the superscripts, and a natbib solution to that may be found under [Superscript page numbers with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51646/15925)

Comment: Perfect!  I had been trying something similar using the `notes2bib` package, but this works much better.  Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this automatically? For the record, I'm required to use this citation format for a paper.

Comment: @MatthewAdams I guess one could write a `.bst` file that would do this.  However, I would be more inclined to try to write a such thing in `biblatex` with `biber`.  I suggest you post a separate question asking for this.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, the bibliography should have one reference if different sections of the same article are cited.  However, you could do it like this, maybe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
In \cite[pp. 45]{bake67} blah, blah blah

\ldots

Baker also shows\cite[pp. 48]{bake67}

\bibliography{junk}

\end{document}
------------
JUNK.BIB

@ARTICLE{bake67,
        TITLE   = "Prediction and scaling of reflected impulse from
                        strong blast waves",
        AUTHOR  = "Baker, W. E.",
        JOURNAL = "International Journal of Mechanical Sciences",
        VOLUME  = "9",
        NUMBER  = "1",
        PAGES   = "45--51",
        YEAR    = "1967"                        }
```

[image]

Does this capture what you are trying to do?

Comment: unfortunately, no.  Science publications I've seen typically use superscript citations, putting the page numbers in-line in the text is not an option.  Also, this doesn't really handle my test case, since if the two things cited together need to be on different pages, this won't work

Comment: @David Hollman : Sorry about that. If you want, I'll leave my post here for the time being to help show others what you are not looking for. Once an aswer gets accepted by you, I will delete this post, or I can delete it now, if you prefer.

Comment: That's fine, we can keep it.  It might me useful for someone searching for a similar answer in the future.

Comment: @DavidHollman So, are you looking for two actual different references in the bibliography, or merely a parenthetical phrase following the superscripted reference number?

Comment: Two different references, the second of which should refer back to the first one.

Comment: +1 the marked answer was my original hack for this problem, and your answer of specifying extra details in square brackets was exactly what I was looking for!