# natbib with superscript option does not handle optional parameter well

Tags: citing, natbib, superscripts

I am using `natbib` for citation like so:

```
\usepackage[super, comma, numbers, square, sort]{natbib}
```

With normal citations, e.g.

```
\cite{some-ref}
```

this works as expected.
But when i try to pass an optional argument like so:

```
\cite[Page 2]{some-ref}
```

it comes out wrong. The reference-number is put into brackets with superscript, but the optional argument is put outside of the brackets like normal text, like if I would write

```
\cite{some-ref}Page 2
```

How can I fix this? I want to have the whole citation, including the optional argument as superscript.

Comment: Is that normal (in your field, etc.)?  Having the page number in a superscript seems super odd.  Won't people mistake the page number (or page range) as references to other bibliography items?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the selected answer to this question:

[Superscript page numbers with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51646/superscript-page-numbers-with-natbib)

If your're reading this, I finally managed to succeed in a half-hour long journey through unsolvable captchas, buggy captcha-widgets and hijacking attempts on my clipboard that forced my to re-copy the link on every of my ~10 attempts to post this.

Comment: Or you could just register for an account like nearly everyone else and not have any of these problems... In any event, now you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).