# Problem with superscript citations and page numbers

Tags: citing, cite-package

I am using superscript citations and it mostly is working fine, but when I try to add page numbers, I get a runaway argument error.  An MWE is

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}       % Sets 12pt font, equation numbers on right
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} % Typical maths resource packages
\usepackage{graphics}                 % Packages to allow inclusion of graphics
\usepackage{color}                    % For creating coloured text and background

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}                 % For creating hyperlinks in cross references. It should be after the color package. The option colorlinks produces colored entries without boxes. The option citecolor=blue changes the default green citations to blue.

\usepackage{fancyvrb}%Verbatim
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[dvipdf]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[final]{showlabels}

\usepackage[superscript]{cite} \bibliographystyle{plain}


\title{Stories make us human}

\author{Peter Flom}

 \date{ }



\begin{document}
\maketitle

"Those who can recall and recount the past in ways that shape audience response can have considerable influence over decision making" \cite[p.\,169]{Boyd2009}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{c:/writing/references}


\end{document}
```

Boyd 2009 is in my references and citations to Boyd that do not include page numbers work fine.

Comment: The preamble loads `natbib` and `cite`. Normally one would only load one of the two. `hyperref` should usually be loaded as last (or almost last) package. Packages should be loaded only once (`fancyhdr`). `graphicx` already loads `graphics`, so the latter need not be loaded explicitly.

Comment: Thanks I moved hyperref to the end, that didn't change things.  When I tried commenting out natbib, I got a whole bunch of errors.  I only see one use of fancyhdr (I searched the code).

Comment: Oops, sorry about the `fancyhdr` I confused `fancyvrb` for a second `fancyhdr`. Note that you should only have one `\bibliographystyle` (the code has two `\bibliographystyle{plain}`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to load both `cite` and `natbib`. In most cases it probably does not matter a lot, but here it is an issue as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite[p.\,169]{kullback}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

shows.

To quote the [`natbib` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf), *abstract*, p. 1

> [`natbib`] can also emulate the sorting and compressing functions of the `cite` package [...]. (The `natbib` package, however, is not compatible with either `cite` or `mcite` themselves.)

(This incompatibility is not a big issue for most use cases since `natbib` usually offers a superset of the features of `cite`.)

The document will only compile without error if you comment out one of the two `\usepackage`s.

Unfortunately, neither package yields the output you presumably expected, because neither package supports superscript citations with page numbers/postnotes.

- `cite` will just full on refuse to typeset the citation as superscript and will produce the normal "[1, p. 169]" instead.
- With `natbib` you get a superscript citation, but the page number will just be dumped after the superscript as normal text in normal size on the baseline.

  - In [Superscript page numbers with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51646/35864) Gonzalo Medina presents a redefinition that convinces `natbib` to print page numbers/postnotes even in superscript citations.